# Create top column layer for select columns/hierarchal columns

Tags: python

I want a top column for fruits. How can I do that?

What I want is highlighted.

[image]

Comment: Using what package?  What have you already tried?

Comment: Pandas. I tried several things from Stack, lost track.

Comment: Can you please add your code?

Comment: pandas has [multi-index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html)